# Asp.net MVC 5 does not resolve View-Path when using Sub-Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I'm trying to implement some `sub-controller` mechanism. I've the following structure:

1. `/Controller/Admin/UserController.cs`
2. `/Views/Admin/User/Index.cshtml`

I'm registering the route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: Administration
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Admin/User/Index.cshtml"); // <---
    }
}
```

My problem is, that this only works when I return the exact view. When
I pass no `View`, the automatic resolving of the path does not work. For example this does not work:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: Administration
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); // <--- Not working
    }
}
```

Why does this is not working with `sub-controller`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because you view would need to be in `/Views/User/Index.cshtml` but it sound like you really should be using [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) in your app.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I've read about them. I'll take a close look and try to use tham. Thanks for your quick comment!

Comment: Just as a side note, you can configure the view engine to look in other folders (the defaults are `/VIews/ControllerName` and `/Views/Shared`, but I suspect that Areas is what you want.